# MVC: Using data from Controller passed back to the View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Controller which performs a check prior to returning a View to prevent someone trying to delete a client if they are linked to another table. If a link is present my list will have some items in it.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    //First check if the ClientID is linked to an environment
    List<Models.Environment> tempEnv = db.EnvironmentsRepo.Find(x => x.ClientID == id).ToList();
    if(tempEnv.Count > 0)
        return View("~/ClientsAdmin/Delete.cshtml", tempEnv);
}
```

View:

```
@model TNT_Client.Models.Client
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Delete Client</h2>
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Selected Client</h4>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I am returning the tempEnv variable along with my view, is there a way I can access that variable from my view? For example, maybe assign it where the `ViewBag.Title` and `Layout` variables live?

Comment: I'm surprised this works *at all*.  The view is expecting a model of `TNT_Client.Models.Client` and you're passing it a `List<Models.Environment>`.  I would think the framework would throw an error for that.

Comment: It actually returns `return RedirectToAction("Index")`. I'm just trying to pass back some information to the view from my controller and I'm unsure how to do that (hence my question! :) )

Comment: `"It actually returns return RedirectToAction("In‌​dex")"` - Can you show the *actual* code in the question then?  Nobody here can guess what you're looking at on your screen.

Comment: Because that is the code we are changing, ei we DON'T want it to do that anymore. That old code doesn't do what we'd like so we're trying something and need a little help with it (which is what you see above)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make a hidden field in your form so that it gets send to server when the user clicks submit button

something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="tempEnv"/>
```

and then in your controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id, string tempEnv)
```

Updated:

If you want to use it inside your view all you need to do is use the ViewBag property.

in your controller

```
List<Models.Environment> tempEnv = db.EnvironmentsRepo.Find(x => x.ClientID == id).ToList();
ViewBag.TempEnv = tempEnv;
```

in your view

```
@if (ViewBag.TempEnv.Count > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: My apologies I've worded my question rather badly. What I'm after is being able to use that tempEnv variable inside my view. For example, being able to do something like: @if(tempEnv.Count > 0)

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's exactly what we were after!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can add `ViewBag.tempEnv = tempEnv.Count`.

Then in your view where ViewBag.Title is you can do `var tempEnv = @ViewBag.tempEnv`